# Hacer que animación se active con Scroll en cada elemento

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animación

tengo un problemilla y resulta que quiero ejecutar una animación, en varios elementos, cuando el scroll de la pantalla llegue a ellos, el problema es que cuando el scroll llega al primer elemento, se activa la animación en todos a la vez, y quiero que se vaya activando, a medida que llegue a cada elemento. Os adjunto mi código.
Los elementos a aniamr son los que tienen la clase animated y la clase que lleva la animación qeu quiero añadirles, cuando el scroll les aclance es animation-in

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
        <style>
            .animation-in {
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-name: global-animation;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.animated {
    opacity: 0;
    height: -webkit-fit-content;
    height: -moz-fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
}
@keyframes global-animation {
 0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(32px) perspective(300px);
}
100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0) perspective(0);
}
}
        </style>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    $(document).scroll(function(){
     var windowHeight = $(window).height()*0.8;
        if($(this).scrollTop() >= $('.animated',this).offset().top - windowHeight) {
          
            $(".animated").addClass("animation-in")
        } else {
            $(".animated").removeClass("animation-in");
        }
      
    });
});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="animated"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="animated"></div>
        </div>
        
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En teoría, estás analizando la posición de un elemento respecto al desplazamiento: `$(this).scrollTop() >= $('.animated', this).offset().top - windowHeight`, sin embargo, aplicas la animación a todos los elementos con la misma clase: `$(".animated").addClass("animation-in");`

Deberías crear un ciclo donde recorras y compares cada uno, para manipularlo de forma individual; teniendo en cuenta que dentro del ciclo `$(this)` va a hacer referencia al elemento correspondiente a cada iteración, por lo que se debe usar `$(document)` para obtener el desplazamiento del documento:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).scroll(function(){
        let windowHeight = $(window).height()*0.8;
        // Recorrer cada elemento
        $('.animated').each(function(i) {
            // Analizar posición del elemento actual
            if($(document).scrollTop() >= $(this).offset().top - windowHeight) {
                $(this).addClass('animation-in');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('animation-in');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.animated {
    background:#ccc;
    margin:200px 0;
}
.animation-in {
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-name: global-animation;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.animated {
    opacity: 0;
    height: -webkit-fit-content;
    height: -moz-fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
}
@keyframes global-animation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(32px) perspective(300px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0) perspective(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="animated">Animar 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="animated">Animar 2</div>
        </div>
```

**Nota:** Agregué contenido en los elementos y estilo CSS solo para ver que funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Te puedo sugerir lo siguiente: [waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/)

En donde podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementById('yourID'),
  handler: function(direction) {
    // do your stuff (you can use "this" to refer to the element)
  }
})
```

con jQuery

```
$('#yourID').waypoint(function(direction) {
  // do your stuff
}, options)
```

Ref a la pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66387457/how-to-detect-the-id-of-a-div-when-i-scroll